# Mesh a hollow cylinder

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

Questions seems to be simple answerde, but in Mathemtica v11.0.1 I didn't find a solution

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
scheibe =ParametricRegion[{  r Cos[\[CurlyPhi]], r Sin[\[CurlyPhi]], 
z}, {{r, 1/2, 1}, {\[CurlyPhi], 0, 2 Pi}, {z, -1, 1}}];
RegionPlot3D[scheibe, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

The region `scheibe` is ok  but meshing

```
ToElementMesh[scheibe] 
DiscretizeGraphics [scheibe]
```

fails in both cases.

What could be the reason? Is there a workaround?
Thanks.

The purpose behind my question is, I want to solve poisson equation in cylindrical coordinates in a predefined mesh.

Comment: The first case using `ToElementMesh` works for me Mathematica 12.0 running on a Mac. Try: `scheibemesh = ToElementMesh[scheibe]; scheibemesh["Wireframe"]`. The second attempt using `DiscretizeGraphics` doesn't work as this function can only discrete 3D graphics primitives or give approximations to certain types of non-linear primitives. This means that Parametric regions cannot be converted into a mesh using this second method as I understand. Maybe others can help as to why the first doesn't work.

Comment: `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
 RegionProduct[Line[{{-1}, {1}}], Annulus[{0, 0}, {1/2, 1}]]]` might serve as alternative.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks, this gives me a boundary mesh, which might be transformed to 3D mesh...

Comment: @Dunlop Thanks, it seems to be a version problem (ToElementMesh, v11)  Perhaps I'll find workaround to get a 3Dmesh

Answer (score 3):

This works fine in Version 12.0:

```
ToElementMesh[scheibe]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately my version is 11.0.1 . Is there a simple workaround?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, I do not have 11.0.1 installed, but maybe something like this: `ToElementMesh[RegionProduct[Annulus[], Line[{{0}, {1}}]]]["Wireframe"]`

Comment: Thank you, that works. in principle. My problem is I would like to control the mesh structure. I only need around three layers in thickness-direction(much smaller the radial dimension) combined with a "rougher" mesh of the annulus.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, then I think fixing [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/204312/18437) for your version is a good bet.