# How to extrude a planar mesh to a volume slice?

Tags: regions, mesh

Is there an easy way to extrude a planar 2D-mesh to a volume slice?

```
ring = RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, 1], Disk[{0, 0}, 1/2]];
DiscretizeRegion[ring]
```

[image]

The thickness of the slice is assumed to be small and should have only some element layers.

Thanks!

Comment: does `DiscretizeRegion@RegionProduct[Annulus[], Line[{{0},{1/10}}]]` give what you need?

Comment: @kglr Thanks, probably yes, but `%["Wireframe"]`  didn't show the mesh.

Comment: @kglr Sorry, just one remark. The planar mesh contains `~209` points, the volumemesh `~16814`  . That means the mesh  has changed significantly, the restriction "keep the planar meshing in some (3-4) layers" is lost.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want some control over the extruded mesh, under Applications in [`RegionProduct`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionProduct.html), there is a nice example.

```
ring = RegionDifference[Disk[{0, 0}, 1], Disk[{0, 0}, 1/2]];
dr = DiscretizeRegion[ring];
pointsToMesh[data_] :=
  MeshRegion[Transpose[{data}], 
   Line@Table[{i, i + 1}, {i, Length[data] - 1}]];
data = Table[Exp[x], {x, 0., 0.5, 0.1}];
r1 = pointsToMesh[data];
rp = RegionProduct[dr, r1];
MeshRegion[rp, PlotTheme -> "Lines"]
```

[image: ExtrdueMesh]

You can use [`Subdivide`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subdivide.html) in place of `data` if you just want a uniform mesh like so

```
rUniform = pointsToMesh[Subdivide[0, 0.1, 5]]
rpUniform = RegionProduct[dr, rUniform];
MeshRegion[rpUniform, PlotTheme -> "Lines"]
```

Comment: Thanks, yes i want some control. Why `Exp[x]` is needed for `data`?

Comment: It really is just an example of non-uniform grid control.  For example, in a Computational Fluid Dynamics problem, you may want to have a boundary layer mesh at the wall that grows exponentially into the fluid domain.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I added a simple uniform mesh extrusion using `Subdivide` to the answer to complement the non-uniform mesh.

Comment: That'it, thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 7):

I am developing [MeshTools](https://github.com/c3m-labs/MeshTools) package, which contains a convenient function `ExtrudeMesh` just for this purpose.

First we create a quadrilateral mesh on annulus region. It can be structured or unstructured.

```
Needs["MeshTools`"]

mesh2D = AnnulusMesh[{0, 0}, {1/2, 1}, {64, 4}]
mesh2D["Wireframe"]
```

[image: AnnulusMesh]

Then we extrude 2D mesh to 3D with `ExtrudeMesh`. Position and orientation of resulting mesh can be further adjusted with `TransformMesh`.

```
mesh = ExtrudeMesh[mesh2D, 1, 4]
mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm@LightBlue]]
```

[image: PipeMesh]

Structured (!) hexahedral meshes can be also transformed to tetrahedral meshes with `HexToTetrahedronMesh`.

```
HexToTetrahedronMesh[mesh]["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" ->FaceForm@LightBlue]]
```

[image: PipeMesh_Tet]

Comment: Thank you very much. That's what I needed to solve Poisson PDE in a predefined simple mesh.

Comment: ...Unfortuantely it only works in v12 (my version is 11.0.1 )

Comment: Hm, I have tested it with 11.1 and it works. What does it complain about (I don't have 11.0 installed)? If you can fix this yourself I am happy to accept your pull request on GitHub. In general I think I could make the package compatible with 11.0, but I would not like to go back even further.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I have tested my answer also with v11.0.1 (Windows) and it worked fine. What kind of problem did you encounter? I am curious, because I would really like to make my package stable and easy to use.

Comment: I tried to install MeshTools but didn't find the right file in`https://github.com/c3m-labs/MeshTools`

Comment: Now it works! Thank you for the very useful tool!

Comment: Again thanks for your great tool. When I take a predefined mesh, created with MeshTools, inside `NDSolve` I observed, that the mesh of the solution doesn't change.  Is this a property of MeshTool meshes?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann There is nothing special about `ElementMesh` created by MeshTools package and you can always inspect its `FullForm` to see exactly what is inside. For me it is expected that `NDSolve` uses exactly that mesh which is given. Maybe if you define a `Region` for solution domain it may use some adaptive mesh refinement, I don't know?

Comment: Thanks, using NDSolve I observed , that mesh adaption tooks only place when a "poor" mesh was given.