# Nearly equally spaced 3D-mesh

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

How to mesh a volume (3D region) with nearly equaly spaced vertices?

Example: Disk with radius 50 and height 15

```
disk = ImplicitRegion[0 < x^2 + y^2 < 50^2 && 0 < z < 15, {x, y, z}];
```

Is there an easy way to mesh the volume such that the vertices are constrained to around `5`?

I tried

```
ToElementMesh[disk, MaxCellMeasure -> {1 ->100}]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

which only gives a nonuniform mesh

Thanks!

Comment: You can mesh with tetrahedra. Each tetraheada has 4 vertices. Do you just want a total of 5 vertices so that the disk is very poorly meshed?

Comment: @Hugh Yes , 3 or 4 elements along the thickness direction would be ok.

Comment: Could you not make use of the answers given to your similar question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/204197/18437)?

Answer (score 6):

#### Coarse cylinder

Using the `Cylinder` primitive seems to do the trick:

```
MeshRegion[
  DiscretizeRegion[Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 15}}, 50], MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> 100}], 
  PlotTheme -> "Lines", 
  MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Black}
]
```

[image]

#### General region

Notice that the boundary is being discretized finer than you'd like. It looks like if we can workaround this, we could get a coarse mesh with higher quality elements.

One way is through stricter sampling options:

```
cyl = ImplicitRegion[0 < x^2 + y^2 < 50^2 && 0 < z < 15, {x, y, z}];
mr = DiscretizeRegion[cyl, 
  MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> 100, 3 -> 200}, 
  Method -> {"RegionPlot3D", PlotPoints -> 6}
];

MeshCellCount[mr]
```

> ```
> {386, 1990, 2902, 1297}
> ```

```
MeshRegion[mr, PlotTheme -> "Lines", MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Black}]
```

[image]

```
Histogram[PropertyValue[{mr, 3}, MeshCellQuality]]
```

[image]

---

Here's another example:

```
ball = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 50^2, {x, y, z}];

mr1 = DiscretizeRegion[ball, MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> 100}];
mr2 = DiscretizeRegion[ball, MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> 100, 3 -> 200}, 
  Method -> {"RegionPlot3D", PlotPoints -> 6}];

MeshRegion[mr1, PlotTheme -> "Lines", MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Black}]
MeshRegion[mr2, PlotTheme -> "Lines", MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Black}]
```

[image]

```
Histogram[PropertyValue[{mr1, 3}, MeshCellQuality]]
Histogram[PropertyValue[{mr2, 3}, MeshCellQuality]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you , that works fine for a cylinder. If I expand the problem to a flat hollow cylinder(thickness 15, radius 25...75) using `RegionDifference` the number  of elements increase dramatically. Do you have an idea how to avoid ?

Comment: Yes, any boolean operation will effect the triangulation of the model and then we'd need some remeshing scheme. Perhaps in this case you could extrude from 2D? Something coarse like `TriangulateMesh[
 RegionProduct[
  DiscretizeRegion[Annulus[{0, 0}, {25, 75}], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> 100}, AccuracyGoal -> 0], 
  Line[{{0.}, {15.}}]], MaxCellMeasure -> ∞]`.

Answer (score 6):

Structured mesh will give you more control over element size for such basic geometric shapes (e.g. cylinder). My package [MeshTools](https://github.com/c3m-labs/MeshTools) can help you with that.

```
Needs["MeshTools`"]
"Version" /. PacletInformation["MeshTools"]
(* 1.0.0 *)

mesh = CylinderMesh[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 15}}, 50, {10, 3}];
size = Flatten@mesh["MeshElementMeasure"];
quality = Flatten@mesh["Quality"];

mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm@LightBlue, PlotLabel -> $Version]]
```

[image: mesh]

It gives you high quality mesh.

```
Min@quality
(* 0.889 *)
Histogram[quality, {0.05}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, Automatic}]
```

[image: quality]

It works with Mathematica 11.0.1, I have tested it right now.

Comment: your package is very helpful!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a possible way forward. I think the standard meshing algorithm attempt to give you a good circular boundary and then this dictates a general mesh size which is too fine for your purposes. Here I define my own boundary points and then mesh from there. I have your five vertices across the disk thickness and put a similar spacing around the circumference.

```
   Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
 h = 15; (* height *)
    r = 50; (* radius *)
    nn = 79; (* number of edges *)
    pts = Partition[Flatten[Table[
        Table[{r Cos[2 π k/nn], r Sin[2 π k/nn], z}, {k, 0, 
          nn - 1}],
        {z, 0, h, h/4}]], 3];
    Graphics3D[{
      Point[pts]
      }

 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now I make the boundary mesh which is not fine.

```
m = DelaunayMesh[pts];
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[m];
bmesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now the mesh density seems to follow from the boundary

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I don't know how to best check the mesh size within the boundaries. Perhaps someone can suggest a method. Here is a section showing the nodes. There are mid side nodes on each tetrahedra but I think I have your 5 vertices across the thickness.

```
cc = mesh["Coordinates"];
Show[
 Graphics3D[Point[cc], PlotRange -> {All, {0, 10}, All}],
 mesh["Wireframe"]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Also we can look at the mesh quality

```
Histogram[mesh["Quality"]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The histogram suggests that there is a dominant size around 0.8. I am not sure of the units here. Is the horizontal axis the volume of elements?

Does this help?

Comment: The mesh quality can vary from -1 to 1 and you'd need all elements to be above 0 to make a FEA work but the higher the better. This documented in the section called [ElementMesh quality](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html#636469158) in the [ElementMesh generation tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html)

Comment: @Hugh It helps a lot, thanks. In my underlying problem I try to mesh a flat hollow cylinder , but the mesh size exceeds to 100000 elements. I'll try your way...

Comment: @user21 Am I correct in thinking that the meshing starts from the boundary? If so what resolution does it use for i) a plain edge and ii) a cylindrical edge? Are there formula? Can this resolution be prescribed?  I think that what have done here is to replace the circular cylinder with a polygonal cylinder. This has required fewer points to represent the boundaries. Is this correct?

Comment: Have a look at the `AccuracyGoial` option for `ToBoundaryMesh` [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToBoundaryMesh.html#694547233) and in the section [Region Approximation Quality in the ElementMesh generation tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html#396642533). Concerning your last question, I think this is correct.