# How to make the following region?

Tags: regions, syntax, geometry

Consider the following region shown in green:

[image]

It is a part of the annular cylinder with the inner radius $R$ and the outer radius $R+r$, which is cut off from the left and right. Is it possible to get this figure as a `Region` in Mathematica? For the test parameters, we may consider its longitudinal length `dz = 10`, the radii `R = 10`, `r = 2`, and the transverse length of the remaining shell `dx = 2`.

Comment: You can start from `Annulus` to design the 2D section of your 3D solid, then extrude it in 3D using `RegionProduct`. See [How to extrude a planar mesh to a volume slice?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/204197/how-to-extrude-a-planar-mesh-to-a-volume-slice)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`RegionProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionProduct) of an annulus and a line:

```
reg = RegionProduct[Annulus[{0,0},{10,12},{-ArcSin[.2],ArcSin[.2]}], Line[{{0},{10}}]];
```

Visualization:

```
Region @ reg
```

[image]